# View is not updating when Observable Collection Updates in Xamarin Forms

Tags: listview, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, itemsource

I am trying to update my view from RG Pop Plugin once a new item get's added from Pop Up. Although i can see the changes in Observable Collection when i am adding a new Item but the view is not getting updated according to the Observable Collection.

Here is my View Model,

```
public class ReceiptViewModel : AddRecieptModel
    {
        //public ObservableCollection<AddRecieptModel> RecieptsData { get; set; }

        private ObservableCollection<AddRecieptModel> _addRecieptModel;
        public ObservableCollection<AddRecieptModel> RecieptsData
        {
            get { return _addRecieptModel; }

            set
            {
                if (_addRecieptModel == value) return;
                _addRecieptModel = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public ReceiptViewModel()
        {

            Task.Run(async () => { await GetReciepts(); }).Wait();
            this.AddRecieptCommand = new Command(this.AddRecieptClicked);
            this.AddRecieptPopUpCommand = new Command(this.AddRecieptPopUpClicked);
            this.SelectedRecieptCommand = new Command(this.SelectedRecieptClicked);
        }

        private async Task<GetRecieptResponse> GetReciepts()
        {
            JsonValue GetRecieptResponse = await HttpRequestHelper<GetRecieptRequest>.GetRequest(ServiceTypes.GetReciepts, SessionHelper.AccessToken);
            GetRecieptResponse getRecieptResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GetRecieptResponse>(GetRecieptResponse.ToString());
            if (getRecieptResponse.IsSuccess)
            {
                List<AddRecieptModel> lstGetReciepts = getRecieptResponse.LstReciepts.Select(dc => new AddRecieptModel()
                {
                    Name = dc.Name,
                    Price = dc.Price,
                    RecieptID = dc.RecieptID,
                    Status = dc.Status
                }).ToList();

                RecieptsData = new ObservableCollection<AddRecieptModel>();

                foreach (AddRecieptModel getReciept in lstGetReciepts)
                {
                    RecieptsData.Add(getReciept);
                }
            }
            else
            {

            }
            return getRecieptResponse;
        }

        private async void AddRecieptClicked(object obj)
        {
            Task.Run(async () => { await AddReciept(); }).Wait();
        }

        public async Task<AddRecieptResponse> AddReciept()
        {
            AddRecieptRequest addRecieptRequest = new AddRecieptRequest();
            addRecieptRequest.AuthToken = SessionHelper.AccessToken;
            RecieptDTO recieptDTO = new RecieptDTO();
            recieptDTO.AddedOn = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            recieptDTO.Name = Name;
            recieptDTO.Price = Price;
            recieptDTO.RecieptID = RecieptID;
            recieptDTO.Status = ReceiptStatusEnum.New.ToString();
            recieptDTO.StoreID = 0;
            addRecieptRequest.recieptDTO = recieptDTO;
            JsonValue AddRecieptResponse = await HttpRequestHelper<AddRecieptRequest>.POSTreq(ServiceTypes.AddReciept, addRecieptRequest);
            AddRecieptResponse addRecieptResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AddRecieptResponse>(AddRecieptResponse.ToString());
            if (addRecieptResponse.IsSuccess)
            {
                List<AddRecieptModel> lstGetReciepts = addRecieptResponse.LstReciept.Select(dc => new AddRecieptModel()
                {
                    Name = dc.Name,
                    Price = dc.Price,
                    RecieptID = dc.RecieptID,
                    Status = dc.Status
                }).ToList();

                RecieptsData = new ObservableCollection<AddRecieptModel>();

                foreach (AddRecieptModel getReciept in lstGetReciepts)
                {
                    RecieptsData.Add(getReciept);
                }

            }
            return addRecieptResponse;
        }


        public void List1CollectionChanged(Object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Your logic here
        }

        private async void SelectedRecieptClicked(object obj)
        {
            int recieptID = Convert.ToInt32(((RecieptDTO)obj).RecieptID);
            var mdp = (Application.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage);
            var navPage = mdp.Detail as NavigationPage;
            if (navPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Count == 0 ||
                            navPage.Navigation.NavigationStack.Last().GetType() != typeof(ProductList))
            {
                await navPage.PushAsync(new ProductList(recieptID), true);
            }
        }
        private void AddRecieptPopUpClicked(object obj)
        {
            PopupNavigation.PushAsync(new CreateList());
        }
    }
```

Here is my ListView,

```
 <ListView x:Name="ListReceipt" 
                                                  SelectionMode="Single"
                                                  HasUnevenRows="True"      
                                                  ItemsSource="{Binding RecieptsData}">
                        <ListView.Behaviors>
                            <behaviors:ItemTappedBehavior Command="{Binding SelectedRecieptCommand}" />
                        </ListView.Behaviors>

                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <StackLayout Spacing="0">
                                        <Frame 
                                            
                                    HasShadow="True"  
                                    Padding="0"  
                                                
                                    BackgroundColor="White">
                                            <Frame.Margin>
                                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Thickness"  
                                             Android="0"   
                                             iOS="0"/>
                                            </Frame.Margin>
                                            <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0">

                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                                <Label  Grid.Column="0" Margin="17,8" VerticalOptions="Center" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3"
                                               Text="&#xf15b;"
                                               FontSize="75"
                                                    TextColor="Teal"
                                               FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}" />

                                                <!-- Document Name -->
                                                <Label Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" FontFamily="{StaticResource Montserrat-SemiBold}"
                                               Grid.Row="0"
                                               Margin="0,13,0,0"
                                               Text="{Binding Name}"
                                               TextColor="{DynamicResource Gray-900}"
                                               FontSize="14"
                                              
                                                />

                                                <!-- Time -->
                                                <Label Grid.Row="1"
                                               Grid.Column="1"
                                               Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                                   Padding="5"
                                               Text="{Binding Status}"
                                               TextColor="{DynamicResource Gray-700}"
                                               FontSize="14"
                                               FontFamily="{StaticResource Montserrat-Medium}"
                                                />

                                                <!-- Document Size -->
                                                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                                               Grid.Column="2"
                                               Margin="0,0,15,0"
                                                   Padding="5"
                                               Text="{Binding CreatedOn}"
                                               TextColor="{DynamicResource Secondary}"
                                               FontSize="14"
                                               FontFamily="{StaticResource Montserrat-Medium}"
                                                />

                                                <Label Grid.Row="2"
                                               Grid.Column="5"
                                               Margin="0,0,0,10"
                                                   Padding="5"
                                               Text="&#xf044;"
                                                   HorizontalOptions="End"
                                               TextColor="{DynamicResource LightGreen}"
                                               FontSize="20"
                                               FontFamily="{StaticResource FontAwesomeSolid}">

                                                </Label>

                                            </Grid>
                                        </Frame>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does your popup page use the same instance of the VM as the list page?

Comment: Not enough code to tell what's going on. Can you supply a MCVE (minimal, complete, verifiable example? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve